# How to remove a row on table on ajax success?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table of products in a cart that has remove button which removes the product in cart via ajax. On ajax success, I want to remove that table row, however, my code is not working. Here is my form...

```
<form:form modelAttribute="cartProduct" 
           action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/customer/removeFromCart"
           method="post">
    <form:input type="hidden" path="product.productId"
        value="${product.getProduct().getProductId()}" />
    <tr id="cartRow">
        <td><img class="card-img-top img-responsive"
            src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/image?prodId=${product.getProduct().getProductId()}"
            alt="Card image cap" style="height: 120px; width: 100%;"></td>
        <td><h4 class="text-primary"
                style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
                <a href="#">${product.getProduct().getName()}</a>
            </h4> <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${product.getStock() >= 50}">
                    <h6 class="text-success">In stock</h6>
                </c:when>
                <c:when
                    test="${product.getStock() < 50 && product.getStock() > 1}">
                    <h6 class="text-warning">Only ${product.getStock()}
                        left</h6>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <h6 class="text-danger">No stock</h6>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs remove-button">Delete</button></td>
        <td><h4 class="text-danger"
                style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">&#8369;
                ${product.getProduct().getPrice()}</h4></td>
        <td>${product.getQuantity()}</td>
    </tr>
</form:form>
```

And here is my ajax code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var form = $("form");
var url = form.attr("action");
var formMethod = form.attr("method");

form.submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var thisForm = this;

    $.ajax({

        url : url,
        data : $(this).serialize(),
        dataType : 'json',
        type : "POST",
        success : function(cartProduct) {
            $(thisForm).closest('tr').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

});

Please help...

Comment: Such issues happens when you have invalid markup. Table element can't have form as a valid child.

Comment: I edited my code. I placed the form inside the <td> tag. How can I hide the row?

Comment: then that should work. you don't have to change anything except the markup itself. consider `table>tr>td>form` now with your code `tr` will get removed as soon as success block executes.

Comment: Also i want to add `.closest()` jQuery method traverses up in the dom tree so that should work.

Comment: how will the code be using table>tr>td>form? Im sorry im a beginner in jquery

Comment: see `table>tr>td>form` when you have this kind of valid structure then `.closest()` from `form` will get to the specific element which in your case is `tr`. Now you can see `form` has parent `td` and it has parent `tr`, so it finds and does it what you say it to do. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed it thanks to [Jai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059101/jai) for helping me place my form correctly. I got it working by this code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var form = $("form");
var url = form.attr("action");
var formMethod = form.attr("method");

form.submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var thisForm = this;

    //this did the trick
    var thisTableRow = $(this).closest('tr');

    $.ajax({

        url : url,
        data : $(this).serialize(),
        dataType : 'json',
        type : "POST",
        success : function(cartProduct) {
            $(thisTableRow).hide("slow");
        }
    });
});
});
```